# python virtualenv: pip not working

Tags: 16.04, python, pip, virtualenv

I am running a python project into a virtualenv on Ubuntu 16.04. Until now everything was working as it should, i.e. I could install libraries through pip and listing the installed packages. I am not sure what happened but whenever I try to run `pip freeze` I get this at the end of python traceback:

```
File "/home/diego/work/cg/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", 
line 15, in <module>
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getLogger'
```

Do you have an idea what happened and how can I fix this? thanks

Comment: Did you activate the virtualenv?

Comment: @don.joey Yes with  `source venev/bin/activate`

Comment: Did you create a file called `logging.py`?

Comment: @don.joey Well, this project actually contains a folder called `logging` with a file in it called `initialize_logging.py`

Comment: I actually solved the problem moving the `venv` folder to another folder that does not contain subfolder with `logging` name and it works again

Comment: I added my comment as an answer. Feel free to accept to get your question into the answered queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you created a file logging.py or a folder logging that is on the PYTHONPATH and that conflicts with the logging module required for pip to work.